# Deploy trained pytorch model in C++

Tags: c++, pytorch

I have trained pytorch model. I am trying to import it in C++. I have followed the steps mentioned in Pytorch website for this but i am unable to do so. Can anyone please tell me what should i do? I am using this piece of neural network.

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, layers):
        super(MLP,self).__init__()
        'activation function'
        self.activation = nn.Tanh()

        'loss function'
        self.loss_function = nn.MSELoss(reduction ='mean')
    
        'Initialise neural network as a list using nn.Modulelist'  
        self.linears = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(layers[i], layers[i+1]) for i in range(len(layers)-1)])
        
        
        
        
    
        'Xavier Normal Initialization'
        
        for i in range(len(layers)-1):
            
            
            nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.linears[i].weight.data, gain=1.0)
            
            # set biases to zero
            nn.init.zeros_(self.linears[i].bias.data)
            
    'forward pass'
    def forward(self,x):

        x = (x-l_b)/(u_b-l_b)
        x=x.float()
        
       
        
        for i in range(len(layers)-2):
            
            z = self.linears[i](x)
                        
            x = self.activation(z)
            
        x = self.linears[-1](x)
        return x

    
    def loss_bc_init(self,x,y):
        loss_u = self.loss_function(self.forward(x), y)
        return loss_u
```

Please help.

Comment: Deploying a trained model in C++ will be hard. Most of the time, you need to write the same architecture in C++ from scratch.

Comment: What have you tried? On what step you stuck? What's the error msg?

Comment: I have saved my model and create cmake file and try to run it. I am successful with one model but when doing for another one it showing error.

Comment: PyTorch has a version no in C++. LibTorch. Did you ever getting working?